# Xamarin forms distribution profile is not available in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile

I have been releasing App quite frequently but suddenly "Distribution Profile" stopped appearing in my "App signing" option (Visual Studio 2017 /Windows). I can see profile is valid and the certificate health is good.

I have tried many things like:

1- Downloaded certificate & Profile and installed again.
2- Restarted MAC/Visual Studio/Windows

Didn't work. Can't see the profile.

Note: Installed Fastlane and when i click "View details", i can see all my certificates & distribution profile coming over.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is your Bundle Id is same as of the provisional profile?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i checked and can confirm the bundle Id is same.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. This morning I added a development device and therefore edited the development provisioning profile. Xamarin can't find my new profile.
Nothing has been changed, working on this app for years already and have many experience in the provisioning profiles.

Comment: It seems to be a know bug, started after a change from Apple: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/5277

Comment: Thank you @Theos. Should we wait and expect some solution from Apple then?

Comment: Xamarin just approved a pullrequest for fixing this. I don't know how long it will take to have an update available. I think it's high priority, so I'm expecting a fix soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that:

1. Make sure that Bundle ID match your provisional profile.

[image: Bundle ID here]

[image: Can see here]
 2. Make sure that your provisional profile is valid and installed on Mac.

Refer to this document [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos)

Comment: Thanks. Gone through each and every step. Checked all little details and found no solution unfortunately.

Comment: @Sentinel Glad be helpful :)